# What is the difference between making an ajax request using webworker and directly through DOM?

Tags: ajax, html

I want to know whether making ajax request using webworker has any advantages over making an ajax request directly within the DOM.

Answer (score 1):

By making ajax requests in webworkers you can save the performance of APP. ajax request from DOM will eat the app performance and may some times block app UI. The safe way processing high computation is doing it  in webworker.